# How to make global exception filter log errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I've just created a global exception filter as per [Nest's docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters), here it is:

```js
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nestjs/core';

@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}

  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
    const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;

    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();

    const httpStatus =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const responseBody = {
      statusCode: httpStatus,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest()),
    };

    httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), responseBody, httpStatus);
  }
}
```

And it is now catching every exception, but it's also not logging any errors to the console anymore... My question is both how to do it and should I log every error inside my filter?

Comment: You should be able to just add a logger (either by DI or instantiation) and `this.logger.log(exception)`, right? Are you expecting the framework to do something else for you?

Comment: Yup, I can! But isn't it wrong/bad practice/solid breaking? Like, shouldn't I use an interceptor for that?

Comment: You can, but keep in mind that interceptors won't see any errors from `middleware` or from `guards`. This is a problem [I face with my OgmaInterceptor](https://ogma.jaymcdoniel.dev/docs/nestjs/interceptor#what-the-interceptor-does)

Comment: But I would still be catching trough my exception, I would just add an interceptor after the filter, wouldn't I?

Comment: Btw, the way I created my filter, I can't inject my LoggerService on it, any tips?

Comment: How are you binding the filter? And no, you can't put an interceptor after it. A filter is __the last__ place to handle custom code in the case of an error

Comment: `{
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: GlobalExceptionsFilter,
    },`

But I just figured I need a LoggerService (custom) inside my filter... What do I do?